# Defining \ang in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

My Problem: I see that `siunitx` needs Latex3 support. Unfortunately I don't have this support (with respect to using latex on a server for which I am not admin). An older version of `siunitx.sty` (2009/03/29 v2.0alpha) works for me until I want to use `\ang`. So

Hence

My Question: what is the explicit macro I need so that I can have `\ang` and continue using the older version of `siunitx`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the units `\degree`, `\arcminute` and `\arcsecond` directly.

Here is a simple parser that acts similar to the current `\ang` macro.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\listfiles
\makeatletter
\def\ang{\kernel@ifnextchar[\ang@{\ang@[]}}
\def\ang@[#1]#2{\def\@tempb{[{#1}]}\@ang#2;;;\@nil}
\def\@ang#1;#2;#3;#4\@nil{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \@@ang{#1}{\degree}%
  \@@ang{#2}{\arcminute}%
  \@@ang{#3}{\arcsecond}%
}
\def\@@ang#1#2{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
   \if@tempswa
    \expandafter\SI\@tempb{0}{#2}%
   \fi
  \else
    \expandafter\SI\@tempb{#1}{#2}%
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ang{0.1} \quad \ang{1;2} \quad \ang{2;30;59}

\ang{;0.2} \quad \ang[symbols/math/degree=^?]{;;3} % just for fun, don't use this!
\end{document}
```

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 siunitx.sty    2009/03/29 v2.0alpha A comprehensive (SI) units package
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
```

### Output

[image]